# Get a single document with Angular 2

Tags: mongodb, typescript, angular

I'm following the [angular 2 Tutorial of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) guide and trying to get and display a single Hero from mongoDb when I go to the hero detail section (as seen in the tutorial). I'm able to find my users (heroes) in mongo running a node backend but not the single hero when accessing that section.

hero.service.ts

```
//The part that gives me errors.
private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/admin/users';

constructor(private http: Http) { }

  //Works
  getHeroes() {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Hero[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  //Doesn't work      
  getHero(_id: number) {
    return this.getHeroes()
      //How should I work with the _id?
      .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero._id === _id));
  }
  //:note that this worked properly when I had the documents in memory with a mock api. Where the ids initially where numbers.
```

It seems to me that the id must be numeric:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

> The /detail/ part of that URL is constant. The trailing numeric id part changes from hero to hero. We need to represent that variable part of the route with a parameter (or token) that stands for the hero's id.

and that the ObjectId I get from mongoDb doesn't work well together with this. If I change the number parameter to be string instead and parse the id to be a string it doesn't work either, and I didn't expect it to either because I don't know what I'm doing at the moment!.

```
getHero(_id: String)
```

anyway... When I run my typeScript compiler I get this error:

```
app/+heroes/hero.service.ts(24,65): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I don't really understand how this work in angular 2/typeScript, sorry that don't know either exactly what to ask for regarding my problem.

app.routes.ts

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: HeroDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  }
];
```

My app recognizes the id and sends me to the correct path: `http://localhost:8080/detail/5773fbc1383ec4868619f1fa`
But whilst on the page no data is found.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

In my dashboard this is how I navigate to the hero's own route.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero [] = [];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private heroService: HeroService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  gotoDetail(hero: Hero) {
    let link = ['/detail', hero._id];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }
}
```

Everything from the example tutorial expects the id of the returned data to be numeric. And If I change the number value to be string instead in..

```
//hero.ts
    export class Hero {
     _id: number;
     name: string;
    }
```

and all other places where this occur I get a bunch of errors, I can't show every place, this would result in to much example code.

My REST API in node:
(That works as expected when using postman)

```
//server/routes/admin.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');


router.get('/users', /*isAdmin,*/ function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users){
      if (err)
        return res.send(err);
      res.json(users);
    });
  });
  //CRUD operations for a single Company by its id
  router.route('/users/:id')
    .get(/*isAdmin, */function(req, res){
      User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
        if (err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(user);
      });
    })
```

How would I do to find one single document from mongoDb with respect to its _id with angular from the client? Anything that could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a specific HTTP route for retrieving a single hero/document. Here is how it should be done in the client :

```
getHero(_id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl + '/' + _id)
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => response.json() as Hero)
         .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I suppose you should have a route :

```
router.get('/users/:id', /*isAdmin, */function(req, res){
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(user);
  });
})
```

Comment: This seems resonable but unfortunately it didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: Ok, I just read your tutorial, this in an in-memory database and so it seems you don't deal with a real web API.  But, since you use a localhost url, I imagine you've done a node REST API. Can you show us the code for your node API ? I think it miss something.

Comment: Yes that is correct. As I said I'm able to get all users returned from my REST API but not for the single user. I'll make sure to add the server snippet as well.

Comment: Yes but it still doesn't work as expected. In my server console it looks like this: GET /admin/users/NaN 200 3.129 ms - 135 with your approach. So it still seems that angular is not able to send the routes correctly. I haven't declared _id anywhere, but I don't know how and when to do it for the document in aspect.

Comment: When you create a document in any collection, mongodb add automatically an `_id` to this document. I don't know what is wrong in your regular process. If you save an hero using POST request, you'll get it as expected using the GET request I showed you.